# Подгрузка связей laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5.7

выполняю запрос на вывод постов выбранного тега

```
$tag = Tag::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        $articles = DB::table('articles')
                        ->leftJoin('article_tags', 'articles.id', 'article_tags.article_id')
                        ->select('articles.*')
                        ->where('article_tags.tag_id', $tag->id)
                        ->where('articles.published', '=', 1)->orderBy('articles.view', 'desc')->paginate(15);
```

в шаблоне пытаюсь вывести теги соответствующего поста

```
@forelse($article->atags as $tag)
    <li><a href="{{route('tagsArticles', $tag->tag->slug)}}">{{$tag->tag->title}}</a></li>
     @empty
@endforelse
```

но выдает ошибку

Undefined property: stdClass::$atags (View:post-tag.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Все дело в том, что Вы сейчас пользуетесь [механизмом прямого обращения к базе данных](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database) для получения $articles. Он реализован через [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php), соответственно, возвращает "что положено" - массив объектов `stdClass`, представляющий результат выполнения оператора SQL. Там будет по 1 объекту на строчку выборки. При этом Вы надеетесь получить функциональность, являющуюся частью [модели Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent). А это возможно только если Вы будете пользоваться механизмом доступа к данным, предусмотренным Eloquent. Как в случае с получением тэгов через модель `Tag`:

```php
$articles = Article::where('article_tags.tag_id', $tag->id)
->where('articles.published', '=', 1)->get();
```

Ну, естественно, нужно добавить недостающие условия выборки.

P.S. В не очень понятных случаях (типа Вашего) полезно посмотреть, что находится в переменной. Для этого удобно воспользоваться встроенной функцией Laravel `dd($variable1, $variable2, ...)`